# Can I suspend a process except one thread?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, system

I'm going to suspend(or pause) a process except one thread.

I've tried to use SuspendThread(Api Function) and the result is process thread was became non-responsable status.

This is not what I wanted. I want to make resume one thread which I must do major work.

How can I solve this? Please give your idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a list of threads belonging to a process. Once you have that list just iterate though it and suspend every thread that doesn't match the current thread ID. The example below is untested but should work just fine.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

// Pass 0 as the targetProcessId to suspend threads in the current process
void DoSuspendThread(DWORD targetProcessId, DWORD targetThreadId)
{
    HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        THREADENTRY32 te;
        te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
        if (Thread32First(h, &te))
        {
            do
            {
                if (te.dwSize >= FIELD_OFFSET(THREADENTRY32, th32OwnerProcessID) + sizeof(te.th32OwnerProcessID)) 
                {
                    // Suspend all threads EXCEPT the one we want to keep running
                    if(te.th32ThreadID != targetThreadId && te.th32OwnerProcessID == targetProcessId)
                    {
                        HANDLE thread = ::OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, te.th32ThreadID);
                        if(thread != NULL)
                        {
                            SuspendThread(thread);
                            CloseHandle(thread);
                        }
                    }
                }
                te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
            } while (Thread32Next(h, &te));
        }
        CloseHandle(h);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately ,I couldn't include "windows.h". Because I didn't use MFC. I must implement CreateToolhelp32SnapShot function by c code. How can I do it?

Comment: `CreateToolhelp32SnapShot` is decalred in `tlhelp32.h`. Just remove the include for windows.h and you should be ok. If that doesn't resolve the compile issue you may need to add "tlhelp32.h" in your stdafx.h file.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
When I code build and run, My computer is suspended.
I only need to suspend a process.
Please tell me the way.

Comment: I 'm going to get my process thread list and then suspend all threads except special thread id.

Comment: If you are trying to suspend threads in an remote process you need to specify the process id when you call CreateToolhelp32SnapShot. Also make sure that you do not suspend the current thread. If you do it will never finish looping and suspending the threads. I recommend you read the docs for CreateToolhelp32SnapShot.

Comment: I have edited your code and it works good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Hate it when I miss things like that ;)

Answer (score -1):

as far as i know you cannot suspend a process except one thread...because when the process exits all threads will also get exit. if you want instead of a thread you can spawn a child process and use it..

Comment: You can but Windows does not provide a single API call to do it.